Relationship many to many between address and employee with a primary one
I have this scenario where an employee can have many addresses so we create a relational table EmployeeAddress, now in the team they suggested to add an AddressId in the Employee table which is going to be the primary one and then in the EmployeeAddress having the rest of addresses, of course, the one you assign as primary should be one the addresses coming in EmployeeAddress table, is this a good approach or it's better to always go to EmployeeAddress and put a column there IsPrimary to go and find the main one?


It's hard to say which way is better, but you can consider use scenarios, programming difficulty, maintainability, data size, database load, and more. Here is a comparison I made.



Scenario
Add AddressId in Employee
Add IsPrimary in EmployeeAddress




Display primary address in employee info page
If need not show AddressType.Name, only need to JOIN EmployeeAddress and Address, otherwise JOIN all 4 tables
JOIN all 4 tables


Displays all addresses of an employee, and indicates the current primary address. (e.g. when providing the optional addresses to change an employee's primary address)
JOIN all 4 tables
JOIN EmployeeAddress, Address, AddressType


Adds a new address as primary address for an employee(Assumed that the address types are already preset and stable)
Commit insert into Employee, EmployeeAddress, Address in a transation
Commit insert into EmployeeAddress, Address in a transation


Adds a new address that is not primary address for an employee
Insert into EmployeeAddress, Address
Insert into EmployeeAddress, Address


Switches primary address of an employee
Update 1 row in Employee
Update 2 row in EmployeeAddress


If primary address is required
Use NOT NULL constraint
Has to program(in database or client)


Maintains the uniqueness of each employee's primary address
It is
Has to program(in database or client)


Table space to use
Nearly every row of AddressId in Employee has value
Lots of NULL in IsPrimay of EmployeeAddress


Others
Typically, Employee contains lots of columns to store employee's infomation, This means that there might be different use cases for updating the Employee at the same time, concurrent locks have more chances.  Larger table means longer transation time, This might make more negative effects on this case(primary address) and other use cases.
The use case of Address and EmployeeAddress are very simple, the chances of concurrent operations on the same employee address are much smaller, and the tables are much smaller, transation commit is faster.



My thinking is, if the Employee is not designed to have a lot of capacity, it would be more convenient to use AddressID in Employee, otherwise use IsPrimary in EmployeeAddress will be more scalable.
Hope this is useful for your discussion.

Thank you Rodger!

My preference for this would be to add a flag to the EmployeeAddress table indicating that it's the primary address.
There are caveats, however.  Something, either the app or a trigger must enforce that only one address can be the primary at a time.  This can be done by looking at all the addresses for an employee and making sure that only one is checked, or it can be that the primary address is indeed on the Employee table and then just putting it there.
... Which is a long way of saying that I can see arguments both ways.  I think that normal forms would say to put the IsPrimary flag on the EmployeeAddress table as that's the most appropriate place for it.

Thank you Jonathan!
